# Openlayers 3 center map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm sing [OpenLayers 3](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/) to display a map. I want to center the map using latLon coordinates.
I'm using the [quickstart code](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/doc/quickstart.html) to begin with.
Using this code, I cannot change the center of the map. I think this has something to do with `Spherical Mercator projection`. Only thing is, I only have lat lon coordinates.

Does anyone know how to center a map from openlayers v3?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to transform the lon/lat coordinates to the correct projection (or coordinate system) using

```
var olCoordinates = ol.proj.transform([lon, lat],"WGS84", "EPSG:900913")
```

Now you can set center with olCorrdinates.

Different projections has different code names. WGS84 is "normal" lon/lat and EPSG:900913 is the projection often used in web maps like google maps, openstreetmap and bing.

I think OpenLayers 3 has built in support for transforming from WGS84/EPSG:4326 (lon/lat), but if you need to convert to or from other coordinate systems you can include the proj4js library. Openlayers will integrate with this lib and be able to do the transformations in the same way.

Transform documentation
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.proj.html

Proj4 lib
https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js

Edit:
In the example you are refering to, the center location is actually set with lon/lat.

```
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4
})
```

EPSG:4326 is actually the same as WGS84 and EPSG:3857 is the same as EPSG:900913. This is very confusing. I have been there myself.

You just need to change the numbers 37.41 and 8.82 to your lon/lat coordinates. If you want to change the center location after initialization you will need to use setCenter();

```
map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
```

Comment: What is that: "WGS84", "EPSG:900913"? I see these things on a lot of site, but I do not really understand what it is.

Comment: It is a map projection or coordinate system. There are multiple ways to measure out the world and these are just codenames on different ways to do it. WGS84 are lon/lat and EPSG:900913 is the one used by openstreetmap, google, bing etc. There are also others like UTM-projections which spits the world into small rectangles and use the metric system as coordinates.

Comment: Also take care of the order of the arguments. The ol.proj.transform method expects [longitude, latitude], whereas some program use the latitude/longitude order of arguments. For example when selecting 'what's here' from the context menu of a Google map the location is shown as latitude/longitude.

Answer (score 14):

OpenLayers introduced [`ol.proj.fromLonLat`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html#fromLonLat) and [`ol.proj.toLonLat`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html#toLonLat) functions [on Mar. 2015](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/commit/5579dc53a225533ca6062a84cb986f1f378e1e47).

To center the map, you may want to use it during the initialization

```
view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat])
      })
```

or after the map has been created

```
map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]))
```

Although they're [just wrappers](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.6.0/src/ol/proj/proj.js#L615) of [`ol.proj.transform`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html#transform), I find them more simple to use.

The default Web Mercators are `EPSG:4326` and `EPSG:3857`.

Like [Ole Borgersen states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820784/openlayers-3-center-map/#27821212), `WGS84` is the same as `EPSG:4326` which is the type of Long-Lat coordinates we are used to work with.

```
ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]);
// is equivalent of
ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')

ol.proj.toLonLat([lon, lat]);
// is equivalent of
ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
```

Answer (score 2):

depends on how you use?

For browser-only use :

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js'></script>


  ol.proj.transform() 

  ol.proj.transform([long, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

For js-app use

```
   // for projection
  import {transform} from 'ol/proj.js';

  // use this one : transform([-118.246521, 34.049039], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')





   var map = new Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      //center: [-118.246521, 34.049039],
        center: transform([-118.246521, 34.049039], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 16
    })
  });
```